# VirtualBox guest can ping host but not access internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kubuntu, virtualbox-networking

I exported a VirtualBox VM (Debian 7.11) from Mac and imported it on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 17.04). Everything seems to work fine, except my imported machine can't connect to the internet.

(I guess I did not change the MAC addresses on import as that failed for some reason that I did not investigated further.)

Here's the current setup:

- VirtualBox is configured to have a "NatNetwork" and a "Host-only network"
- For the VM both network adapters are active and cable is connected.
- On the host and inside the VM there is a OpenVPN configuration (the same on both machines). But it is not activated for now.

## The guest machine

```
# /etc/init.d/openvpn status
[FAIL] VPN 'vpn' is not running ... failed!

# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e7:5d:aa  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee7:5daa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1830 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:21368 (20.8 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cb:4b:40  
          inet addr:192.168.56.120  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecb:4b40/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2247873 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:638995 (624.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:49216 (48.0 KiB)  TX bytes:49216 (48.0 KiB)

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Now the test:

```
# ping -c 1 192.168.56.1
PING 192.168.56.1 (192.168.56.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.831 ms

--- 192.168.56.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.831/0.831/0.831/0.000 ms

# wget 172.217.21.206 # google.com
--2017-05-25 17:31:28--  http://172.217.21.206/
Connecting to 172.217.21.206:80... failed: No route to host.
```

## The host machine

```
# /etc/init.d/openvpn status
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-05-25 17:33:12 CEST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 1280 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

# ifconfig 
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:ee:75:c6:13:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

enx0050b6dfa166: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.26  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::1682:e4a2:aca4:9424  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:b6:df:a1:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1310132  bytes 1599207507 (1.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 840018  bytes 90022576 (90.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7627  bytes 379131 (379.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7627  bytes 379131 (379.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3557  bytes 299336 (299.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:1d:1b:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 06:eb:85:c3:6b:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx0050b6dfa166
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx0050b6dfa166
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx0050b6dfa166

# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

And the tests:

```
# ping -c1 192.168.56.120
PING 192.168.56.120 (192.168.56.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.120: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.66 ms

--- 192.168.56.120 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.664/1.664/1.664/0.000 ms

# wget 172.217.21.206 # google.com
--2017-05-25 17:39:15--  http://172.217.21.206/
Connecting to 172.217.21.206:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2017-05-25 17:39:15--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 172.217.22.196
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|172.217.22.196|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=o_omWdH5KefVXp7imGA [following]
--2017-05-25 17:39:15--  http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=o_omWdH5KefVXp7imGA
Resolving www.google.de (www.google.de)... 216.58.207.131
Connecting to www.google.de (www.google.de)|216.58.207.131|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                        [ <=>                                            ]  11,05K  --.-KB/s    in 0,003s  

2017-05-25 17:39:15 (4,11 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [11316]
```

So on the host normal internet access is available and the guest machine is available via network. (I can even ssh into the VM from the host.)

What I tried additionally:

- `iptables -F` on the host

What am I missing? On the Mac machine it works without problems (in the same network).

Is something missing in the iptables configuration? Or should that be handled from VirtualBox itself?

Comment: What are the VM's network settings? it looks like you have both a NAT (10.2.0.x) and a host-only (192.168.56.x) interface configured

Comment: @steeldriver: Yes that's correct. That's how the VM was configured when I got it from my customer on the MacBook. Not sure if that is needed because of the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after releasing and re-attaching a Linux VDI in order to make a backup.  Could ping external sites from within the VB session, but not load pages.  Tried multiple configs of the network adapter (NAT / Bridged).

In the end, got it to work by disabling Adapter 1 and instead enabling Adapter 2 (as Bridged), which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: you need to change DNS settings

If you have output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` something like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver ::1
```

Than change your dns settings: run `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

And add text to the file:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```